# How to display RelativeLayout (MapView) with perfectly rounded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm using `mapview` on main `Relative Layout`

I want to mapView to be completely rounded.

I searched it for in internet get answer saying that I should make new drawable xml and add it to Layout that I want to make it rounded by `setBackgorund(R.drawable.xxxx)`.

so, I made `layout_bg.xml` in drawable folder.

**layout_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!-- solid background -->
        <solid android:color="#ffffba54"/>
        <!-- border-->
        <stroke
            android:color="#ffff206a"
            android:width="2dp"
            />
        <corners android:radius="25dp"/>
        <!-- different corners with different radius-->
        <!--corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
            /-->
    </shape>
</item>
```

but It's not working at all. 
so, I tried to do it in programmatically.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 mapView = new MapView(this);
    ViewGroup mapViewContainer = (ViewGroup)  
    findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapViewContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.layout_bg); 
                           <--- Here I get error. because R.drawable.layout_bg is int

    Log.e("mp","mapView2");
    mapViewContainer.addView(mapView);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:text="aaaaaaaa" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(MainActivity.this).getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layout_bg)` then you wont get the error.. !!